# Double router port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I recently bought new router to home: NETGEAR R6220. I prevously had one: TP-LINK TD-W8950N. I could forward any ports i needed, but now it's harder. I'm using setup like this

[image]

How can i make it work?
I tried port forwarding from TP-LINK to NETGEAR, and on second router to computer, but that doesn't work. I also tried setting up DMZ, but that also fails.

Comment: Configure Router 1 to DMZ to Router 2.  You then only have to forward ports on a single router.

Comment: @Ramhound i did it, and it doesn't work, but i will try again